# My method won't let me leave a for loop while going through an array

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a method which adds a new vehicle(Honda) to the `vehicles` array. The array contains a maximum of 4 vehicles.

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[4];
```

The method is supposed to add 1 new `Vehicle` object to the end of the `vehicles` array if there is a `null` value. The problem is that it is writing to ALL of the `null` values in the array instead of just writing to 1 and then kicking out of the `for` loop.

Here is what I have (NOTE -- I am required to use an array instead of `ArrayList`):

```
public void addVehicle(Vehicle Honda[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    boolean found = false;
    if(canAddVehicle() == true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length || !found; i++)
        {
            if(vehicles[i] == null)
            {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
                Honda[i] = new Vehicle();
                Honda[i].readRecord(reader);
                vehicles[i] = Honda[i];
                reader.close();
                found = true;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Vehicle Added!");

    }
}
```

I've set `found = true` to make sure it leaves the for loop as soon as it finds the first `null` value in the array.. but it doesn't seem to be working. Why would this be?

**EDIT:** Also, I am not allowed to have any other class level data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `||` when you should be using `&&`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length && !found; i++)
```

More information on the conditional operators can be found in [this Java Tutorials article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

As a friendly critique, this isn't very readable to another developer. The following would be easier to follow:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++)
{
    if(vehicles[i] == null)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        Honda[i] = new Vehicle();
        Honda[i].readRecord(reader);
        vehicles[i] = Honda[i];
        reader.close();
        break; //break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you could use a break inside a For loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length || !found; i++)` use `for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length && !found; i++)`

Replace the or operator `||` with the and operator `&&`. Basically it was seeing that found was true, but i was still less than vehicles.length so the loop continued. With `&&` both need to be true in order for it to run.